# Custom Voice Actions

Tags: android, voice, google-voice-actions

The [Google Developer video on voice actions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OW1A4XFRuyc) states that it is possible to implement custom voice actions. The example given is:

```
Ok Google, Shazam this song
```

Evidently this is not one of the [system voice actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) (take a picture, set an alarm, etc). The link provided by the video points to the [Custom Voice Actions](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions) page, which states:

```
For example, developers have implemented commands like "scan my receipt on Walmart"
or "watch trailer for Inception on Flixster."
```

However there doesn't appear to be any explanation of how to implement custom voice actions, and the page crypticly states that:

```
Note: We are not accepting requests for Custom Voice Actions.
Stay tuned to Voice Actions - Google Developers and +GoogleDevelopers for product updates.
```

Does this mean that custom voice actions are not possible at all - or perhaps they need to be specifically approved by Google?

I'd like to implement a custom voice action so I could say a custom phrase such as `Ok Google, Foo Bar` which would be picked up by my own activity. Is this possible?

*Edit: This has to be performed when the app is not already running - just for clarification.*

Comment: Very old thread this one, but a year later, the page still states exactly the same. Anyone knows if there's any update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may implement the system voice actions presented [here](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) to get basic voice action functionality. Totally custom voice actions are not possible at the moment.